# async await with Select() in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a `ViewComponent`, and `DTO` and `ViewModel` classes. I want to pass a list of `ViewModels` to the view, but because of `async/await` I cannot do it in one line like so:

```
 List<PageVM> pages = await _context.Pages.ToArray().Where(x => x.Slug != "home").OrderBy(x => x.Sorting).Select(x => new PageVM(x)).ToList();
```

I can do it in more lines like so:

```
List<PageVM> pages = new List<PageVM>();

List<PageDTO> dto = await _context.Pages.Where(x => x.Slug != "home").ToListAsync();

foreach (var item in dto)
{
    pages.Add(new PageVM(item));
}
```

But is it possible to modify the one line so it works with `await`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is; note the parentheses:

```
var pages = (await _context.Pages.Where(x => x.Slug != "home").ToListAsync()).Select(x => new PageVM(x)).ToList();
```

However, this is equivalent to the following two statements:

```
var dtos = await _context.Pages.Where(x => x.Slug != "home").ToListAsync();
var pages = dtos.Select(x => new PageVM(x)).ToList();
```

which IMO is much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to wrap the awaited expression with parenthesis.
Something like this should do.

```
List<PageVM> pages = (await _context.Pages.Where(x => x.Slug != "home").ToListAsync())
.Select(item => new PageVM(item)).ToList();
```